# How do i compare my guess with other computers to get the highest bid

Tags: java

How can I make this print out the highest bid in java?

I am trying to make a Price is Right game but i cant figure out how to print the highest bidder

```
    int computerOne = random.nextInt(2000) + 1001;
    int computerTwo = random.nextInt(2000) + 1;
    int computerThree = 0;

    if (userGuess > computerOne) {
        computerThree = random.nextInt(userGuess) + (2000);
    } else if (userGuess < computerTwo) {
        computerThree = random.nextInt(computerOne - 500) + (userGuess+1);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Alright everyone's bids are in: \n\tContestant 1: $" + userGuess + " \n\tContestant 2: $" + computerOne + " \n\tContestant 3: $" + computerTwo + "\n\tContestant 4: $" + computerThree);

    int correctPrice = random.nextInt(400)+201;
    System.out.println("The retail price of the item was $" + correctPrice);

    int userDiff = (correctPrice - userGuess);

    int computerDiff1 = (correctPrice - computerOne);

    int computerDiff2 = (correctPrice - computerTwo);

    int computerDiff3 = (correctPrice - computerThree);


    if (userGuess < computerOne && userGuess < computerTwo && userGuess < computerThree)
        System.out.println("Player one wins");
    else if (userGuess < computerTwo && userGuess < computerOne && userGuess < computerThree)
        System.out.println("Player two wins");
    else if (userGuess < computerThree && userGuess < computerOne && userGuess < computerTwo)
    System.out.println("Player three wins");
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Cna you share a sample output you're getting and explain why it's wrong?

Comment: Have you learned how to create classes yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list to track all the bids so you can iterate the list instead of having to write so many different if/else conditions. That is very error prone.

This is how I suggest doing it if you haven't learned to write your own classes yet. Make a list of the bids. Iterate the list to find the best bid that fits the criteria of being no more than the `correctPrice`. At the same time, keep track of which index of the list corresponds with the best bid found. Then you can use that to name the winner. You can use a negative value for the default index so you know if no one made a valid bid.

The following example code would replace the `int userDiff` line and everything below it.

```
var bids = List.of(userGuess, computerOne, computerTwo, computerThree);

int bestBid = 0;
int bestBidIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < bids.size(); i++) {
    int bid = bids.get(i);
    if (bid > bestBid && bid <= correctPrice) {
        bestBid = bid;
        bestBidIndex = i;
    }
}
if (bestBidIndex >= 0) {
    var winner = "Contestent " + (bestBidIndex + 1);
    System.out.println("The winner is " + winner + " with a guess of $" + bestBid + ".");
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no winner. All players busted.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable called highest bid, and compare it to each of the existing bids.

IE-

```
int highestBid = computerOne;
if (computerTwo > highestBid)
    highestBid = computerTwo;
```

Putting this into some sort of list of bids would make this cleaner and easier to sort through.